# hide filter in pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2016

I created a pivot table from the following data:

```
Salesperson   |   Amount   |   Include?
John          |   100      |   Yes
Jane          |   350      |   Yes
Jim           |   200      |   No
Jack          |   150      |   Yes
```

My Rows is Salesperson, my Values is Sum of Amount and Include is my Filter.
I want the filter to only include values where Include is Yes. This is working fine but I do not want the filter to be visible in the report.

Is it possible to hide this?

Report looks like:

```
Include?    |    Yes (dropdown) (filter row)
------------------------------- (blank row)
Salesperson |    Sum of Sales   (header row)
Data Here...                    (data rows...)
```

I do not want the filter row or blank row to show up.

**Edit** I should also mention that I do not want to hide the entire row in Excel because I have data in different columns that I want to show.

Comment: You can add a slicer for that field and move it to the bottom of the sheet.

Comment: If you're only concerned about the printed report, you can format the cells to be white text on a white fill or whatever color the rest of your sheet is. That will hide it when printing but the drop-down will still be visible to someone editing the sheet so it's not perfect.

Comment: @EngineerToast I want the row header to be on the first row. Similar reason to why I can't hide the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Create a pivot table place the "include?" field to the column and the salesperson field to the row.

Drag the salesperson to the value and use the count function.

[image: The pivot table will be]